# Spring Integration Email Redelivery on Exception

Tags: email, jms, spring-integration

I have a web service that via a GET Http method, the user requests for a person object. This person is sent to a JMS Queue and then with the help of Spring Integration, I send it to a fake email address (https://papercut.codeplex.com/). I have written the code with Spring Integration Java DSL. I would like to ask:

1. Is there a more flexible way to send the email message?
2. If an exception is thrown, how can the mail be redelivered with the help of Spring Integration? (e.g. for 5 times and if it is not sent then the exception gets handled and the program stops)
   Here is my code:

**Web Service**

```
     public Person findById(Integer id) {
        Person person = jpaPersonRepository.findOne(id);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("testQueue", person);
        return jpaPersonRepository.findOne(id);
     }
```

**Java Confiuration**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableIntegration
    @ComponentScan
    public class JavaConfig {
        private static final String DEFAULT_BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";
        private static final String DEFAULT_QUEUE = "testQueue";

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
         ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
         connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
         return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory());
        template.setDefaultDestinationName(DEFAULT_QUEUE);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer() {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        defaultMessageListenerContainer.setDestinationName(DEFAULT_QUEUE);
        defaultMessageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory());
        return defaultMessageListenerContainer;
}

    @Bean(name="inputChannel")
    public DirectChannel directChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

   @Bean
   public IntegrationFlow orders() {
        return IntegrationFlows
        .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(defaultMessageListenerContainer()))
            .transform(new ObjectToStringTransformer())
            .enrichHeaders(p -> p.header(MailHeaders.TO, "Papercut0@test.com"))
        .handle(Mail.outboundAdapter("127.0.0.1")
                   .credentials("test","test").port(25)
                   .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "true")), 
                    e -> e.id("sendMailEndpoint"))
        .get();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a more flexible way to send the email message?

Sorry, the question isn't clear. You have enough short code to do that. `Mail.outboundAdapter()` and all its fluent API. What should be more flexible?

> If an exception is thrown, how can the mail be redelivered with the help of Spring Integration?

For this purpose Spring Integration suggests `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`. And `Mail.outboundAdapter()` can be configured with that as:

```
@Bean
public Advice retryAdvice() {
    RequestHandlerRetryAdvice advice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    advice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
    advice.setRecoveryCallback(new ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer(emailErrorChannel()));
    return advice;
} 

...

.handle(Mail.outboundAdapter("127.0.0.1")
               .credentials("test","test").port(25)
               .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "true")), 
                e -> e.id("sendMailEndpoint")
                      .advice(retryAdvice())) // HERE IS THE TRICK!
```

See its JavaDocs and [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) on the matter.

Comment: Thanks! Your answers were clear. The .advice(retryAdvice()) especially, helped me a lot.